# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: No data received: Unable to load the webpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cidr

I just deployed a .NET application using SQL Server via Elastic Beanstalk.

It seems like my newly deployed application can't connect to my database. I just followed this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-N0z5K_WFI (except I encountered issues during deployment where I had to untick incremental deploy)

I was able to connect to the db using SQL management studio. I also tried running the app locally while connecting to the amazon RDS db and has success. After deployment, checking the site and trying to login/register, I get this error:

No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

The only thing in my mind right now is that my EC2 or application can't connect to the Database.

Is this a CIDR issue?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to consider -

1. Is the port for your RDS database instance being blocked?
2. When you deployed your app, you should have seen a page in the wizard asking if you wanted the EC2 security group for your deployed Elastic Beanstalk instance to be added to the RDS security group for your database instance. You need to checkmark the relevant RDS security group too.

There's also an updated video from last year's AWS re:Invent conference that shows deployment of a SQL Server based app to RDS/Elastic Beanstalk - http://youtu.be/5N352oeYmqE

Hope this helps.